# Is the Caffeinated/modules plugin for Laravel still maintained?

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade

I'm currently in the process of upgrading a Laravel 5.2 project (yes, I know, I know...) to the latest Laravel version (9 at the time of writing). This project uses Caffeinated/Modules to structure the code - currently on version 3.

On checking the compatibilities using Laravel Shift, it appears there is no version of Caffeinated/Modules compatible with Laravel 9. In addition, on checking the Modules project on GitHub, no updates have been made to it in the past year - which is slightly worrying.

So I'm wondering if this plugin is effectively obsolete? (or soon-to-be?)

Does anyone know if there are any plans to keep it going in the future? Or is it worth ditching it now?

(For background, I tried a single "shift" from 5.2 to 5.3, and so far have been unable to get the Module routes to work. I wonder if the Modules could be the biggest headache in the upgrade process).

Any insider knowledge/advice/experience gratefully received!

Comment: I suspect you'd be more likely to get an answer to this question on the projects [GitHub](https://github.com/caffeinated/modules). Looking at the most recent commit (March 2021) and an [open issue requesting Laravel 9 support](https://github.com/caffeinated/modules/issues/440) from February 2022, you'll likely want to look for alternatives or fork the project and support it yourself or through the community.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes there are a lot of pleas for Laravel 9 support on there. The only answer given is to send an email to a particular individual, which I have done - but I'm not holding my breath! It feels like this is a product that's no longer supported, and perhaps the most sustainable solution is to revert to the standard Laravel project structure.

Answer (score 0):

No.Last version came out: Mar 27, 2021. You can not install it on Laravel 9 and 10.